# how to find the correlation between categorical and numerical columns

Tags: python, correlation

I'm trying to find the correlation between categorical and numerical columns in my dataset using Python, can anyone help?
Here is the data that I have.
Thank you in advance.

| Light_Sensor_Reading | Light_Sensor_Status |
| --- | --- |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 231 | Dim |
| 232 | Dim |
| 950 | Very_bright |
| 988 | Very_bright |
| 987 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 986 | Very_bright |
| 985 | Very_bright |
| 985 | Very_bright |

Comment: What do you mean by correlation? What do you want to achieve with this correlation?

Comment: @RaJa I want to confirm that both of them have the same meaning and have relationship and we must remove one of them to remove redundancy

Comment: @lolowa What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @PhanNhatHuy a −1≤  number ≤+1, as per knowledge.. the value that is > 0 considered positively correlated and we must keep one of the columns thank you

Comment: Correlation is defined only between numerical variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check this by plotting the data. The colors have to be somewhat horizontally

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=df.index, y='Light_Sensor_Reading', hue='Light_Sensor_Status')
```

[image: Result of plot]

Comment: first of all, thank you very much.. as i'm new in this field I would be thankful if you can give me a clarification of the graph?

Comment: Well, it is relatively straight forward. The scatter function just plots all your datapoints, coloring them according to your categorical variable. Now, if there is a correletaion, all the orange values need to be let's say above 900, while all the blue values should be below 300. That's what I meant with "somewhat horizontally". If you have a single orange point below 300 it might be mis-classified or if there are more then you have no correlation.

Comment: Yes That's support my point that they are redundant ! thx

Answer (score 2):

Correlation here feels a bit wrong, but I guess you could factorize the status.

Assuming you have your data in a Pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
from pandas import factorize

labels, categories = factorize(df["Light_Sensor_Status"])
df["labels"] = labels
abs(df["Light_Sensor_Reading"].corr(df["labels"]))
```

Correlation should give you a value of `0.9998202098949396`.

Comment: first of all, thank you for you answer but what do you mean by "Correlation here feels a bit wrong"? you mean the accepted answer ?

Comment: I mean I agree with @AdrienC. It doesn't make real sense to calculate correlation between those variables. What I suggested is a trick for this case. :-P

Answer (score 2):

I encode the status as number then use the dataframe pearson correlation function to return the correlation

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
Light_Sensor_Reading=[231, 231,231,231,231,231,231,231,231,232,950,988,987,986,986,986,986,986,986,986,986,986,986,985,985]
Light_Sensor_Status=['Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Dim','Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright', 'Very_bright',   'Very_bright', 'Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright',\
'Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright','Very_bright']

df=pd.DataFrame({'light_sensor_reading': Light_Sensor_Reading,'light_sensor_status':Light_Sensor_Status})
x=range(len(df))
sns.scatterplot(x=x, y='light_sensor_reading',data=df,hue='light_sensor_status')
plt.show()
encoder=LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(df['light_sensor_status'])
df['light_sensor_status_enc']=encoder.transform(df['light_sensor_status'])
corr=df['light_sensor_reading'].corr(df['light_sensor_status_enc'])
print("correlation ",corr)
```

output:

```
correlation  0.9998202098949396
```

Comment: This will only work for binary classes. More than two classes, and it will get you in trouble.

Comment: Ok, but the example only have two states

Comment: you can one hot encode the categorical data and then use softmax with categorical cross entropy to get an answer

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't mean anything to calculate the correlation between two variables if they are not quantitative.

I think what you want to do is to study the link between them.

The purpose is to explain the first variable with the other one through a model.

You can use the logistic regression.

But you will only know if there is a link between these two variables with a T-Test or a wilcoxon test depending on the normality of the data